# In Flash, despite publishing for "export in frame 2", many classes seem to be in frame 1, why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I decided to add a preloader, so I wrapped the content of frame 1 in an object and moved it all to frame 2.  I assigned the document class to that new object in the library, and cleared the document class from the publish settings, effectively detaching the document class from the main timeline.

I went into Actionscript Settings and set the "Export classes in frame:" option to "2".  If you look in the library, each symbol's option for "export in frame 1" now says "export in frame 2", so I have to assume it means what it says.

Despite frame 1 being empty, and despite the ActionScript setting to export classes in frame 2.... the generated size report still reports that most of the classes are exported in frame 1.

I have one SWC file referenced which is set to be "merged into code", but shouldn't that data be defined in frame 2 as well?  Again, the size report is showing most imported definitions defined on frame 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out rather quickly.

The problem seems to be having an instance of the main document class on frame 2.  By simply having an instance there, its creating a variable of that type on the main timeline, hence it needs to have that definition loaded to instantiate the main timeline for frame 1.

The solution is to make sure that the ***entire*** main timeline does not in any way reference any classes you don't want loaded in frame one, especially your document class.  Instead, instantiate your main document class *via code* on frame 2 with the "getDefinitionByName" utility function.